# Codoforum: Could not integrate sso login with existing website

Tags: php, single-sign-on

I am noob into CODOFORUM, i am trying to login user using existing Database. I am trying to integrate SSO Login library given in documentation of CF. But i don't understand how to integrate it, 
Here are my settings of SSO plugin: [sso plugin settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLVlL.png)

When i enable plugin it takes me to the form.php but after entering email & password and clicking login a blank page is displayed.

If you please give me any example of how to do this task, that would be awesome. (As there is not enough Documentation on this topic).

Link to library with **client.php** and **sso.php**
https://github.com/evnix/codoforum-sso

Comment: please provide the code as text (formatted as code), not as an image

Comment: updated with library link. I have not made any change to code except client id and client secret